# Can Cosmos SDK3 Container be a singleton?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I would like to reduce load on Azure Cosmos DB SQL-API, which is called from a .NET Core Web API with dependency injection.

In App Insights, I have noticed that every call to the Web API results in GetDatabase and GetCollection calls to Cosmos which can take 5s to run when Cosmos is under heavy load.

I have made `CosmosClient` a singleton (e.g advice here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/performance-tips-dotnet-sdk-v3-sql)

However I could not find any advice for whether the `Database` or `Container` objects could also be singletons so these are created for each request to the Web API.

I check for the existence of the database and collection (e.g. following advice here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclient.getdatabase?view=azure-dotnet#remarks and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclient.getcontainer?view=azure-dotnet#remarks)

This means that for every request to the Web API, the following code is run

```
var databaseResponse = await this.cosmosClient.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(
    this.databaseConfiguration.DatabaseName,
    throughput: this.databaseConfiguration.DatabaseLevelThroughput);
var database = databaseResponse.Database;
var containerResponse = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerId, partitionKey);
var container = containerResponse.Container;
```

Can I make `Database` and `Container` singletons and add them to the DI to be injected like `CosmosClient` in order to reduce the number of calls to GetDatabase and GetCollection seen in App Insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `CreateIfNotExistsAsync` every time, if you know that they are available, you can use `CosmosClient.GetContainer(dbName, containerName)` which is a lightweight proxy class.

Unless you are expecting the database and containers to be deleted dynamically at some point?

Comment: Can the `Container` instance returned by `CosmosClient.GetContainer(dbName, containerName` be kept for the lifetime of the application like `CosmosClient`? e.g. I wrap the Cosmos `Container` in a "repository" class. In this repository class the `Container` is lazily instantiated on first use. If the repository class is a singleton then, the `Container` instance would exist for the lifetime of the application and be accessed by multiple threads. Would this cause problems.

Comment: e.g. are `Container` instances threadsafe like `CosmosClient`

Comment: Yes, `Container` instance is just a proxy, nothing more. There is no overhead or network calls when calling `GetContainer`, so you can keep a single instance and it will be thread-safe

Comment: Hi, there is also a discussion on github regarding this topic and seems that Container could be hold as singleton - [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/829)

Answer (score 4):

According to the latest [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-api-dotnet-application), you create a CosmosClient Service singleton, which owns the Containers you will be working with.   In affect making the Containers singletons as well.

First, make your interface contract:

```
public interface ICosmosDbService
{
    // identify the database CRUD operations you need
}
```

Second, define your Service based on the contract:

```
public class CosmosDbService : ICosmosDbService
{
    private Container _container;

    public CosmosDbService(CosmosClient dbClient, string databaseName, string containerName)
    {
        this._container = dbClient.GetContainer(databaseName, containerName);
    }
    
    // your database CRUD operations go here using the Container field(s)
}
```

Third, create a method in your Startup class to return a CosmosClient:

```
private static async Task<CosmosDbService> InitializeCosmosClientAsync(IConfigurationSection cosmosConfig)
{
    var databaseName = cosmosConfig.GetSection("DatabaseName").Value;
    var containerName = cosmosConfig.GetSection("ContainerName").Value;
    var account = cosmosConfig.GetSection("Account").Value;
    var key = cosmosConfig.GetSection("Key").Value;
    var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient(account, key);
    var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
    await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/id");
    return new CosmosDbService(client, databaseName, containerName);
}
```

Finally, add your CosmosClient to the ServiceCollection:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var cosmosConfig = this.Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb");
    var cosmosClient = InitializeCosmosClientAsync(cosmosConfig).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService>(cosmosClient);
}
```

Now your CosmosClient has only been created once (with all the Containers), and it will be reused each time you get it through Dependency Injection.

Comment: How do we inject a generic service which can query different containers?

Comment: CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync returns a ContainerResponse, that already has a property with the Container reference. You might as well provide that to the constructor no?

Answer (score 0):

`CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync` should only be called once as it is just a setup step for DB configuration.

You'd better create a DbService to persist the container object. And inject the DbService into each services instead of the DB client

Comment: Thanks - I'd like to do this. But I can't find any documentation about whether it's safe for the `Container` to be kept for the lifetime of the application (unlike `CosmosClient` where the docs say it's ok). Do you know if the `Container` instance is safe to keep for the duration of the application and threadsafe?

Comment: found a doc for repository pattern with cosmos DB: [Repository Pattern with Azure Cosmos DB SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/partitionedrepository/repository-pattern-with-azure-cosmos-db-sql-api/). In the sample repo: [PartitionedRepository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/PartitionedRepository), the author init a new client in each query...I don't know whether it's a good practice

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand the sample repo. They persist the IDocumentClient  object and wrap it with a DB client. maybe you can read the code as a reference